# Add arbitrary metadata to mp4 file

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, gstreamer, mp4

is there any mechanism to add my own metadata like `name=xyz` to an mp4 file.
I know as mentioned here https://superuser.com/questions/1208273/add-new-and-non-defined-metadata-to-a-mp4-file ffmpeg and gstreamer can add some metadata but that only predefined, i want to add my own metadata in the MP4 file itself. Adding via gstreamer/ffmpeg would be good.

Comment: Try the mp4box tool,

Comment: @Gyan thanks for comment, i am not getting an example to add arbitrary metadata to the mp4 file using mp4box, would be good if you can give an example for same

Comment: Sorry; doesn't look it supports arbitrary tags.